# Transport problem wth time management

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-modeling

Are there general methods for solving the transportation problem with additional conditions:

- Time management (transportation from point A to point B is so much)
- Transportation of more than one product at the same time (X and Y once)
- Dependence on other goods (carriage Z depends on X and Y)

I'm familiar with how these problems are solved separately (transportation, distribution of resources, etc.), but the question is how to combine them? Can anyone suggest lectures, articles or books on this area (and in general, what area of ​​mathematics involved such things), with simple explanation of these things?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. From the FAQ: Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. http://math.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Ok, I edited question. I don't suggest to solve these problem just determine area. It's scoped question.